# c# Webrequest through https (configured) proxy (The ServicePointManager does not support proxies of https scheme)

Tags: c#, https, proxy, servicepointmanager

I need to connect to a https-url by using a proxy which also has a https address. My code is simply like this:

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://reallywhatsthepoint.com");
var proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("https://proxyaddress:port"));
webRequest.Proxy = proxy;
WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
```

Doing this I get a well known Error:

> The ServicePointManager does not support proxies of https scheme

No credential-code here for simplicity. And no, the users will not change the proxy to http.

Now there are some hints, that this cannot be achieved like:
[Microsoft blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2007/04/25/the-servicepointmanager-does-not-support-proxies-of-https-scheme-net-1-1-sp1/) or [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/22904d47-073a-431c-8b85-1684412a99b0/connection-to-soap-webservice-via-https-proxy?forum=wcf) but these are all a little old and [this](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS#Encrypted_browser-Squid_connection) states, that at least Chrome and Firefox seem to have a solution to that issue.

Can anyone tell me, how to get to a https address through a proxy which itself can only be reached through https?

The ServicePointManager should be able to do this by now, is there some development?

Thx!!

Comment: Is there no need for this? Anyone?